# memory leaks found but no stack trace is shown

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I started looking for the `memory leaks` when I received memory warning.I have read some  material on how to solve memory leaks but when I run `Instruments` things shown seem a bit abnormal to me. The `call tree` is empty and the `extended detail` panel is showing no stack trace. Also I am not able to understand the graph shown in `Root Leaks(cycles & roots)` I have attached the screenshots below.

[screenshot: cycles & roots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCbmi.png)

[Leaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRnpT.png)

Answer (score 1):

Ray Wenderlich and his team explain this sort of thing very nicely.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/instruments-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-debug-memory-leaks

Time for more studying. :o)